# How to share memory in a thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I am trying to use the memory I allocated in the main function inside the thread function, but I am getting the error: `undefined reference to 'product_line'`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "test1.c"

int main()
{
    char** product_line;
    product_line = malloc(sizeof(char *));

    product_line[0] = "Toy";    
    product_line[1] = "Chair";
    product_line[2] = "Door";

    pthread_t thread_tid;
    pthread_create(&thread_tid, NULL, foo, NULL);

    pthread_join(thread_tid, NULL);

return 0;
}
```

This is the separate source the thread calls:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

extern char** product_line;

void * foo(void *param)
{
    int i;
    printf("%s\n", product_line[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%s\n", product_line[i]);
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Including `.c` source file is unusual.

Comment: You allocate space for one pointer, then use three of them:((

Comment: Should I use another method to include the file?

Comment: Threads are a red herring here. Even if you called the thread function directly it wouldn't work. Simple reason: `product_line` is local in `main()` while a different `product_line` is declared globally but never fully defined. Two different objects in different scopes can have the same name within their scopes.

Comment: All the threads of the same process share the same virtual address space. But you should care about synchronization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `product_line` should be declared outside of `main`, otherwise it is not accessible from other translation units:

```
/* main.c */
…

char **product_line;

int main()
{
    …
}
```

---

Another issue mentioned by MikeCAT:

> Including `.c` source file is unusual.

Consider adding a header file `test1.h`:

```
/* test1.h */
#ifndef TEST1_H
#define TEST1_H

void * foo(void *param);

#endif
```

Then, replace `#include "test1.c"` in `main.c` with:

```
#include "test1.h"
```

This is needed to avoid duplicate definitions of `foo` when `main.c` and `test1.c` are both compiled.  (Assuming you are compiling the code with something akin to `cc main.c test1.c`.)  It is recommended (albeit optional) to also include `test1.h` in `test1.c`.

---

Martin James also mentioned:

> You allocate space for one pointer, then use three of them:((

This line

```
product_line = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

allocates space for a single `char *` pointer.  However, you are actually using 3 of them, so you need to allocate 3 `char *` pointers:

```
product_line = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `product_line` is not accessible because it is a local variable, not a global variable.

Making `product_line` global is a easy way to fix.

Another solution is to pass `product_line` as the parameter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void * foo(void *param)
{
    char** product_line = param;
    int i;
    printf("%s\n", product_line[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%s\n", product_line[i]);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char** product_line; /* strings literals are not modifyable */
    product_line = malloc(sizeof(const char *) * 3); /* Do allocate enough buffer! */
    if (product_line == NULL) /* You should check if malloc() was successful. */
    {
        perror("malloc");
        return 1;
    }
    product_line[0] = "Toy";
    product_line[1] = "Chair";
    product_line[2] = "Door";

    pthread_t thread_tid;
    pthread_create(&thread_tid, NULL, foo, product_line);

    pthread_join(thread_tid, NULL);

    free(product_line); /* You should free() what you allocatted via malloc(). */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should know the difference between local(auto) variable and global variables.

Scope of variable in the following link:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

If you read the previous tutorial, you'll be able to detect the error by yourself. The `product_line` variable is auto which means it will be created in stack area once you entered "main" function and destroyed by getting out of it.

So, this variable is not available for `foo` function; not on its stack.
Suggested solutions:

- Make a global pointer which is avaiable for your all functions
- Add new argument for `foo` function and pass this pointer to it.

**Note:**

It is not common to include .c file, include .h instead which has prototypes and defined types for this module.